# <div> tag id repeats in while loop

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am developing a small web application using JSP, was successful in retrieving the data and my task is to group the data under tabs using bootstrap tabbed menu. The real task is to display the data based  on the tab click. But when i try to display more then one row in single tab, it is displaying only the last row (value). Its because the div tag id is getting repeated. Please find the below code and tell me where i had done the mistake.( i want to group the id if it repeats, but i am unable to find it)

My HTML CODE:

```
while (rs1.next()) {
                    PositionID = rs1.getString(1);
                    PositionTitle = rs1.getString(2);
                    StudentID = rs1.getString(7);
                    Bio = rs1.getString(10);
                    ProfileID = rs1.getString(11);
        %>

            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="<%=PositionTitle%>">
                <%

                %>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="radio" name="<%=ProfileID%>"
                        value="<%=ProfileID%>"><%=FirstName%>,
                    <%=LastName%><br>
                </div>

            </div>


            <%




                    }
                %>
                </div>
            <%

                    connection.close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());
                    }
                %>
```

[image: This is the inspect element snap shot, based the code the id is getting repeated]

Comment: Relation with jQuery or JavaScript ?

Comment: Is it possible to group all ID under same parent Div tag? using jQuery or JS.

Comment: If can it be on back-end its much better. DOM manipulation is last solution.

Comment: Back-end  Hopeless. can we use classes instead of id's to group tabbed menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a solution with javascript but, if you have a solution in back-end you must use it.

Firstly if your page have same id more than one thats a bad thing. You have to change id attribute with something else ( like data-id ).

```
var uniqueIds = [];

$(".tab-pane").each( function () {

    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    if ( $.inArray( id, uniqueIds ) == -1 )
        uniqueIds.push( id )

});

for ( var i = 0; i < uniqueIds.length; i++ ) {

    var allItems = $("[data-id='" + uniqueIds[i] + "']");    
    var firstItem = allItems.eq(0);
    var restItems = allItems.not(":eq(0)");

    restItems.appendTo( firstItem )

}
```

I'd create a fiddle for it. You can see it there too.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/vyf1gswv/1/